# ControlValueAccessor: this.onChange is not a function

Tags: angular, controlvalueaccessor

this `ControlValueAccessor` is really driving me crazy.
For some reason it always gives me the following error (when I change a dropdown Value, and also initially):

```
TypeError: this.onChange is not a function.
```

This is my dropdown.component.ts:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dropdown',
  templateUrl: './dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dropdown.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => DropdownComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class DropdownComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @ViewChild(DropdownComponent) ref!: DropdownComponent;

  /**
   * If true, the user can select multiple options.
   */
  @Input() multiple = false;

  /**
   * If true, the dropdown is disabled
   */
  @Input() disabled = false;

  /**
   * If true, the user can search for options.
   */
  @Input() searchable = false;

  /**
   * If true, the user can clear the selected option.
   */
  @Input() clearable = false;
  @Input() placeholder = 'Select an option';

  /**
   * The items of the dropdown.
   *
   */
  @Input() items: DropdownOption[] | any[] = [];

  /**
   * name of the property to use as the display value
   */
  @Input() bindLabel: string = 'label';

  /**
   * name of the property to use as value (e.g. ID)
   */
  @Input() bindValue: string = 'value';

  /**
   * Minimum number of characters the user has to type before the dropdown starts to search for options.
   */
  @Input() minTermLength = 0;

  /**
   * This is the Subject that watches the change in the term typed by the user to fetch results from the server.
   */
  @Input() typeahead!: Subject<string>;

  val = '';

  set value(val: any) {
    // this value is updated by programmatic changes
    if (val !== undefined && this.val !== val) {
      this.val = val;
      this.onChange(val);  // <-- the error happens here.
      this.onTouch(val);   
      
    }
  }

  onChange: any = () => {};
  onTouch: any = () => {};

  constructor() {}

  registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouch = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.disabled = isDisabled;
  }

  writeValue(val: any): void {
    this.value = val;
  }
}
```

The strange thing is that, initially, `registerOnChange` is called. So, `this.onChange` gets assigned and shouldn't be undefined.

Can anybody help please? I would be greatly appreaciated :)

UPDATE:

Here's the implementation of my component. It's being used in storybook:

```
const Template: Story<DropdownComponent> = (args: DropdownComponent) => {
  const value = 'item-2';
  return {
    template: `
      <dh-dropdown [(ngModel)]="value" [items]="items">
      </dh-dropdown>

      <div style="margin-top: 20px">
        <p>Value: {{value}}</p>
      </div>
    `,
    props: {
      ...args,
      items: dropdownItems,
      value,
    },
  };
};
```

Comment: Looks like problem in usage, not in component. I tried in StackBlitz, and it was working. Can you show the code where you set the value?

Comment: Do you see a different result if you define `onChange` as a function instead of arrow function? `function onChange() {  }`

Comment: I just updated my post with my implementation (it's a storybook implementation). Maybe that causes problems. On Friday it worked, with the same code. But I cannot make it work anymore somehow.

Comment: Also, I changed `onChange` to a normal function, no difference unfortunately.

Comment: Still works for me with `ngModel`.. yeah, storybook is just a big headache (=

Comment: Would you mind posting the link for the stackblitz? I would really appreciate that :)

Comment: Sure https://angular-ivy-txjnzf.stackblitz.io

Comment: You can try use `this.onChange && this.onChange(val); `, so if not yet defined not make the "onChange(val)". BTW, In this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7c4bqq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdrop%2Fdrop.component.ts) I try to write your code and looks like work well

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I also rewrote it (in an Angular environment, without storybook), and it works perfectly. So it must have something to do with storybook.